# Sql query of two table referring back to each other

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I have two tables (with column name) :

**Profile (emp_id, emp_fullname)

User (emp_id, emp_name, emp_leader, leader_id)**

I want to select emp_id, emp_fullname from **Profile** table and emp_fullname(leader) from **User** table.
Situation: Based on emp_id from **Profile** table, I would like to refer its leader_id from **User** table, and then get the full name of that particular leader for each of the employee from the profile table.

My question is, how to can i refer back the leader_id from User table to Profile table in order to get his or her fullname. I have try this, but it only gives the emp_id, emp_fullname but not the leader name

```
SELECT p.emp_id, p.emp_fullname, u.emp_fullname
FROM profile p
LEFT JOIN user u ON u.emp_id = p.emp_id
```

Comment: Please tag only the actual dbms you're using

Comment: You need a second join.

Comment: @Solarflare i have tried several query, but it didn't work. can you share a bit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably, `leader_id` refers to another user.  If so, you just need another `join`:

```
SELECT p.emp_id, p.emp_fullname, u.emp_fullname,
       ul.emp_fullname as leader_fullname
FROM profile p LEFT JOIN
     user u
     ON u.emp_id = p.emp_id LEFT JOIN
     user ul
     ON ul.emp_id = u.leader_id;
```